# BCM2835 GPIO Pins vs. Physical Pin Numbers

Tags: gpio, bare-metal, assembly, broadcom

Good morning.

I am attempting some low-level assembly coding for Raspberry Pi. Using the [BCM2835 Peripherals Doc](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2835/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf), I have successfully been able to work with the GPIO controller on my RPi Model B rev. 2.0 to turn the "ACT" LED on (which I know is raw pin number 16), but I want to use this to interact with physical GPIO pins on the board. Seeing as there is no way the physical pin numbers are  the same as the raw pin numbers for the BCM2835, I was hoping there would be a resource explaining what the raw pin numbers would be. Sadly, I haven't found one yet. Could someone point me toward a resource like this or potentially list them out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing a bit of research, as well as testing things out, I discovered that I was misinterpreting what I was hearing about physical pin numbers. The GPIO Pin numbers listed in [official pinouts](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/gpio/README.md) as GPIO## or BCM## do actually correspond to the raw GPIO pin numbers for the Broadcom SoC.